# How to make fb:dialog pop-up on page Load

Tags: facebook

Any suggestion, instead of onClick is it possible to do it onLoad or bodyLoad?

Please give suggestion for both Static FBML and iFrame.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you just need to use

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
  //your method goes here
  FB.ui({
   .....
 });
};
```

Hope it helps...Use FBML instead of iframe